# AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'respond'

Tags: python, discord.py, attributeerror

I can't send ctx messages as ephemeral it says:

AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'respond'

```
await ctx.respond("This is suposed to be ephemeral", ephemeral=True)
```

So How ctx can be ephemeral ?
It only works with interaction ?

EDIT :

tried this

```
await ctx.reply("This is suposed to be ephemeral", ephemeral=True)
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is the discord API's Context object based on the tag, the [Discord API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#context) does not show Context having a respond attribute, which is what you are doing with `ctx.respond`. Were you perhaps thinking of `ctx.reply`?

Comment: But ephemeral is not a parameter in reply that's why

Comment: Nevermind it's not ephemeral I can still see the message with another account

Comment: If you read the docs under reply, it is a shortcut method for Message.send() and has the **kwargs option. If you then look at the send documentation, you will see the ephermal option. reply takes the ephermal option in kwargs and passes it to send.

Comment: I edited. With this I can still see the message with another account and that's a problem !

Comment: According to the docs, ephemeral is only applicable to contexts with an interaction. Does that apply to your context?

Comment: I don't want to use interaction anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So How ctx can be ephemeral?

It can't.

> It only works with interaction?

Yep, exactly.